# Shopify / Liquid - split and delete after split

Tags: shopify, liquid

I would like to split my product titles, e.g.:

```
"big hat - red"
"small coat - blue"
"medium socks - green"
```

so that it **only outputs the text before the "-"**. In other words, I want some kind of dynamic split (or a 'split and delete the remainder' operator/function) that outputs

```
"big hat"
"small coat"
"medium socks"
```

Using the below doesn't remove the text after the hyphen, and I can't simply hard-code the ending part to be removed, because the text after the hypen varies with each product.

```
{{ product.title | split:"-" }}
```

How would I achieve this?

Comment: I wonder if there is an excel-style option to 'find' the "-" and count the number of characters in it is, as part of a possible solution. I cannot find anything on this however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [split](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/filters/string-filters#split) filter and then [first](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/filters/array-filters#first) filter to get first array element.

```
{% assign source_string = "before text - after text"%}
{{ source_string | split: "-" | first }}
```

For your code, it will be

```
{{ product.title | split:"-" | first }}
```